# Outlook (2010) & shared calenders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

The PA for all the "leadership team" where I work has an odd issue with her outlook. She has been granted "author" permission to about 10 calenders.

She says something happened to her machine a couple of weeks ago (details vague) and after IT resolved the issue she noticed that one of the calenders were no longer showing details of appointments, just BUSY or TENTATIVE.

This issue was handed over to IT: This specific calender has been removed & re-added. The permissions granted by the calender owner have been checked, removed, re-added IT have basically given up on this issue.

I have re-done what IT have done (add/remove calender, re-grant permissions...). I have also gone control-panel -> mail... and added a new TEMP mail profile. Once this temp profile was activated the specific details of this one calender were visible (great!!!) but the other 9 were being shown as BUSY or TENTATIVE.

This does show it is something specific with this persons outlook. Anyone ever come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I got to the bottom of it.
All the help on the net todo with this was with regards to no data showing up, not part data.

Turns out it was a network latency issue and (the site we are on has a very small pipe...).
enabling one calender at a time and waiting for it to be fully refreshed sorted it